# Classificação de gramatica no nltk

Tags: python, texto, nltk

Estou usando a lib Natural Language Tool Kit para tratamento de alguns textos e nessa lib  possui o recurso RSLPStemmer() remove quase toda a palavra e deixa o radical.
Mas a palavras Homônimos perfeitos e parônimos o  RSLPStemmes() remove e ao passar para FreqDist  são classificadas como frequências de uma palavra.

A uma forma de lidar com essa situação usando o RSLPStemmer() sem perder a palavra e ao passar para FreqDist sem que
ocorra repetições que não deveria contar ?

Comment: Vc já deu uma olhada na diferença do Porter e Lancaster para stemming?

Comment: não, comecei a ler alguns artigos e ver alguns exemplos dos que mencionei não encontrei nenhuma referencia para estudo dos que você escreveu mas gostaria de compreender melhor, poderia explicar sobre tal diferença desde ja agradeço sua atenção.

Answer (score 1):

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer


def stemming_bag(words, stemmer):
    return [stemmer.stem(w) for w in WORDS]


def imprime(w, result):
    return list(zip(w, result))


WORDS = ["correr", "corria", "correndo", "correio", "corredor", "corredora", "corredeira", "correia"]

porter = stemming_bag(WORDS, nltk.PorterStemmer())
print(imprime(WORDS, porter))


lancaster = stemming_bag(WORDS, nltk.LancasterStemmer())
print(imprime(WORDS, lancaster))

rslp = stemming_bag(WORDS, nltk.stem.RSLPStemmer())
print(imprime(WORDS, rslp))

snowball_pt = stemming_bag(WORDS, SnowballStemmer("portuguese"))
print(imprime(WORDS, snowball_pt))
```

O resultado seria

```
[('correr', 'correr'), ('corria', 'corria'), ('correndo', 'correndo'), ('correio', 'correio'), ('corredor', 'corredor'), ('corredora', 'corredora'), ('corredeira', 'corredeira'), ('correia', 'correia')]
[('correr', 'cor'), ('corria', 'corr'), ('correndo', 'correndo'), ('correio', 'correio'), ('corredor', 'cor'), ('corredora', 'corredor'), ('corredeira', 'corredeir'), ('correia', 'corre')]
[('correr', 'corr'), ('corria', 'corr'), ('correndo', 'corr'), ('correio', 'correi'), ('corredor', 'corr'), ('corredora', 'corr'), ('corredeira', 'corred'), ('correia', 'corre')]
[('correr', 'corr'), ('corria', 'corr'), ('correndo', 'corr'), ('correio', 'correi'), ('corredor', 'corredor'), ('corredora', 'corredor'), ('corredeira', 'corredeir'), ('correia', 'corr')]
```

Particularmente eu usaria o Snowball neste caso.

Porém, caso vc precise da frequência por palavra (ex.: `corredor` é diferente de `corredora`), isso teria que ser feito antes de fazer o stemming.

Veja também sobre [Lemmatization](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-lemmatization-with-nltk/) e olhe a biblioteca [NLPyPort](https://pypi.org/project/NLPyPort/)

Comment: Por exemplo palavras que a escrita é igual mas em analise morfológica seria diferente no texto. COMO a palavra  sede é um substantivo (beber agua cerveja etc)  e sede de localidade. sede da fazenda da empresa, Nesse uso mencionado acho que  daria melhor mas o uso do RSLPStemmer() estragaria o significado morfologico.

Comment: Espero que sejam casos "isolados". Mas, para isso, você pode (i) criar o [POS TAG](http://www.nltk.org/howto/portuguese_en.html) das palavras e/ou (ii) criar o [IOB](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html). Com o IOB, vc pode dar o significado morfológico. O IOB é usado para NER (named entity recognition). O sistema tem que ser treinado e dá um super trabalho montar o arquivo. Com o  NER vc pode, por exemplo, buscar por todos os nomes de empresa ou nomes pessoais.

Comment: Sensacional, muito obrigado por mostrar esse caminho.